# How to avoid creating linking table using @ElementCollection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities - **Person** and **Car**. Instead of mapping them with **@OneToMany** relationship, I decided to use **@ElementCollection** (*storing car ids only*), so that I could have less load on my DB, additionaly fetching cars whenever I fetch *Person*.

But Hibernate keeps creating new linking table like **'person_car_ids'**. So my question is - how do I map **Person** **id** in **'car'** table?

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> carIds = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: If you just map it `@OneToMany`, your car entities won't be loaded.  The fetch type for `@OneToMany` is lazy by default.

Comment: I guess I just didn`t specify that when I fetch Person instances from JPA repository I want it to have cars ids only. I was told the best way to do that was by using ElementCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JPA Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection):

> An ElementCollection can be used to define a one-to-many relationship to an Embeddable object, or a Basic value (such as a collection of Strings). [...] **The ElementCollection values are always stored in a separate table**.

It doesn't say anywhere that it won't use a different table to store your basic values, just makes it more convenient without having to use a wrapper.

To your question:

> I decided to use @ElementCollection (storing car ids only), so that I could have less load on my DB, additionaly fetching cars whenever I fetch Person.

Not sure I got it right, but if you want to fetch cars only when you need them instead of loading them when you fetch a `person` entity, you can use Lazy loading, which is the default when you use `OneToMany` annotation.

Comment: If so then I'll go with OneToMany then. Thanks